# Geotools GeoJSONWriter setEncodeFeatureCollectionCRS not giving any output

Tags: coordinate-system, geojson, java, geotools

I have a very simple Test Class where I try to parse a simple Shapefile (just a few points) to a GeoJson.

```
public class ShapefileToGeoJSON {

    public static void test() throws IOException {
        // Specify the path to the shapefile
        File shapefile = new File("C:\\Users\\Franzi\\Desktop\\Pos2Shp\\test\\test.shp");

        Map map = new HashMap();
        map.put( "url", URLs.fileToUrl(shapefile));
        // Load the shapefile into a GeoTools data store
        DataStore dataStore = DataStoreFinder.getDataStore(map);
        String[] typeNames = dataStore.getTypeNames();
        SimpleFeatureCollection featureCollection = dataStore.getFeatureSource(typeNames[0]).getFeatures();

        //Check CRS
        CoordinateReferenceSystem refsystem = featureCollection.getSchema().getCoordinateReferenceSystem();
        
        // Convert the features to GeoJSON format
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\Franzi\\Desktop\\Pos2Shp\\test9.geojson");
        GeoJSONWriter writer = new GeoJSONWriter(out);    
        writer.setEncodeFeatureCollectionCRS(true);
        writer.setMaxDecimals(10);

        writer.writeFeatureCollection(featureCollection);
        writer.close();

        out.close();

        // Close the data store
        if( dataStore != null ){
            dataStore.dispose();
            dataStore = null;
        }
    }
}
```

It works fine, put the GeoJSON does not contain any information about the CRS like

```
"crs": {
        "type": "name",
        "properties": {
            "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84"
        }
    },
```

even though I use `writer.setEncodeFeatureCollectionCRS(true);`.

The `SimpleFeatureCollection` has a valid `CoordinateReferenceSystem` (GCS_WGS_1984).
Am I missing something or why is this information not showing up in my GeoJSON?

The GeoJSON looks like this

```
{
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [{
            "type": "Feature",
            "properties": {
                "date": "24/04/2023 09:16:54",
                "Attribute1": "Attribute1"
            },
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [9.5124887085, 49.2062567235]
            },
            "id": "test.1"
        }, {
            "type": "Feature",
            "properties": {
                "date": "24/04/2023 09:16:54",
                "Attribute1": "Attribute1"
            },
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [9.5126723183, 49.2060909806]
            },
            "id": "test.2"
        }, {
            "type": "Feature",
            "properties": {
                "date": "24/04/2023 09:16:54",
                "Attribute1": "Attribute1"
            },
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [9.5126597098, 49.2061072381]
            },
            "id": "test.3"
        }
    ]
}
```

I am using Android Studio and Geotools 29.0.

Edit:
I have also tested my code with a shapefile in UTM, still not showing up. The `SimpleFeatureCollection's` `CoordinateReferenceSystem` is correctly set to "ETRS89 / UTM zone 32N".

```
{
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [{
            "type": "Feature",
            "properties": {
                "Date": "28/04/2023 10:20:06",
                "Attribute1": "Attribute1"
            },
            "geometry": {
                "type": "MultiLineString",
                "coordinates": [[[537338.6338488857, 5450491.504021886], [537340.2925363812, 5450492.015228175], [537338.1460640889, 5450491.218172779], [537340.601109487, 5450502.697745162]]]
            },
            "id": "line_utm.1"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't remember if I actually wrote any code for that method but you can check to see. I also suspect that since the default for geojson is wgs84, there is a good chance that we don't bother to write it out to conform to the specification.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I have tested it with another shpefile with ETRS89 / UTM zone 32N, still no crs field showing up.